# how to get the list of all values in a row if particular value found in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to get the values of a row if a value found in a column

for example
this is my df

```
    column1 column11    column16    column17    column19
3   X   VALUE   IP               Ethernet IP    VLAN
5   A   2420    42.842.52.100   42.842.52.100   M
6   B   2423    09.82.02.2049   09.82.02.2049   N
7   Y   2421    42.82.52.1356   42.82.52.1356   O
8   D   2396    542.842.49.113  542.842.49.113  P
…   …   ... ... ... ...
…   …   ... ... ... ...
930 F   2126    42.842.52.100   42.842.52.100   S
931 G   2154    09.82.02.2049   09.82.02.2049   T
932 H   2190    42.82.52.1356   42.82.52.1356   U
933 I   2334    542.842.49.113  542.842.49.113  V
934 J   2224    42.82.207.241   42.82.207.241   W
```

firstly I don't want to consider row1 which is `(column1    column11    column16    column17    column19)`. how can I drop it, it's fixed in my excel sheet, I am not able to drop it and I want to name my column with row2 i.e;`(X    VALUE   IP               Ethernet IP    VLAN)`

here is the main query let suppose I found J in column1 then I want all the values from that column in list i.e;

```
['2224',    '42.82.207.241',    '42.82.207.241',    'W']
```

this is want I have done

```
df3 =pd.read_excel("abcd.xlsx",sheet_name="Values")
df_b = list(df3[df3['column1'].values=="J"])
print(df_b)
```

it is giving me

```
['column1', 'column11', 'column14', 'column16', 'column17']
```

but when I do this :

```
df_b = df3[df3['column1'].values=="J"]
print(df_b)
```

it gives me

```
     column1 column11       column14      column16      column17
 934    J     2224        42.82.207.241 42.82.207.241      W
```

Please suggest what I can do here to get for j and similarly for others.:

```
['2224'    ,   '42.82.207.241'  , '42.82.207.241'   ,   'W']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are unique values in `column1` after filtering get `Series`, so possible convert to `list`:

```
cols = ['column11', 'column14', 'column16', 'column17']
df_b = df3.loc[df3['column1'] == "J", cols].tolist()
```

Another appoach should be select by `column1` converted to `index`:

```
df_b = df3.set_index('column1').loc["J"].tolist()
```